# Mark the record with the lowest value in a group in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, select, case

I have a table that looks like the below:

| ID | ID2 | Name |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 111 | 223 | ABC |
| 111 | 225 | ABC |
| 111 | 227 | ABC |
| 113 | 234 | DEF |
| 113 | 242 | DEF |
| 113 | 248 | DEF |
| 113 | 259 | DEF |
| 113 | 288 | DEF |

What I am trying to achieve is to mark the record that has the lowest value in the ID2 table in every ID1 group doing a select statement, e.g.:

| ID1 | ID2 | Name | R |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 111 | 223 | ABC | Y |
| 111 | 225 | ABC |  |
| 111 | 227 | ABC |  |
| 113 | 234 | DEF | Y |
| 113 | 242 | DEF |  |
| 113 | 248 | DEF |  |
| 113 | 259 | DEF |  |
| 113 | 288 | DEF |  |
| 116 | 350 | GHI | Y |
| 116 | 356 | GHI |  |

How do I achieve this in a SELECT statement?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Get top 1 row of each group](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6841605/get-top-1-row-of-each-group)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The window functions should to the trick .   Use `dense_rank()` if you want to see ties.

```
Select *
      ,R = case when row_number() over (partition by ID1,Name order by ID2) = 1
                then 'Y'
                else '' 
           end
 From  YourTable
```

---

I should add... The window functions can be invaluable.  They are well worth your time experimenting with them.